# Changing owner of profile folder

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have this script

```
$dir = '\\knesmbmdc001\profiles'
$logFile = 'C:\user_done.txt'
Get-ChildItem -Directory $dir | % {
$user = $_.Name
$acl = Get-Acl –LiteralPath $_.FullName
$userIdentity = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount $user
$acl.SetOwner($userIdentity)
Set-Acl –LiteralPath $_.FullName -AclObject $acl
Add-Content $logFile $user
}
```

I get this error

```
Exception calling "SetOwner" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."
Set-Acl : The security identifier is not allowed to be the owner of this object.
```

I'm trying to take the name of the folder(Users name) and set it as the owner.

Comment: If my answer is wrong, please update your question with: provide a `$user` value that fails. Does the `$user` value exist as a user? Do you have multiple domains?

Comment: I get the same error even while using your answer.

Comment: Ok. Still waiting on answers to the questions. :-)

Comment: Do not have multiple domains. $user should be set with the name of the folder

Comment: you still haven't provided a `$user` (or `$folder` in your "answer")-value that fails. We can't check for special characters etc. in a description, we need an actual sample-value. Does it fail for every folder or just  some? Are you sure that the value it fails at is a valid, existing user?

Comment: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1020002-powershell-acl-set-owner-on-sub-folders I followed what was here worked great

Answer (score 0):

The name of the folder is not a valid username. You should output `$user` in your script to see which one fails. I'll assume this is roaming profiles for a Windows domain. I see two potential problems:

1. Does the user exist? Roaming profiles aren't deleted when a user is deleted from the domain, so it might be a deleted user
2. Profiles in Vista and newer might have a version number at the end to avoid mixing profiles between different OSes, ex. `username.v2`. So you need to just extract the name from this.

If (cause -eq 2), try:

```
$user = $_.Name.Split(".")[0]
```